# CSS - replace part of content text

Tags: css

Is there a way using pure CSS to replace part of content text, for example if the text is `ABCDE` -

```
<span class="replacer">ABCDE</span>
```

But instead of `ABCDE` the first 3 chars will be `*` so it will displayed as `***DE`.

Comment: Hi, doing this in pure CSS is not a good option try using JS instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, in pure CSS it's not possible to change the content, but you could cheat by overlapping something, e.g.

```
.replacer { 
  font-family: monospace; 
  position: relative; }

.replacer::before {
   background: #fff;
   position: absolute;
   content: "***";
}
```

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/deJNWv)

or, another tricky way could be creating and loading a special font that maps the symbols `A`, `B` and `C` into the asterisk sign (through the `unicode-range` property, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range)

---

in javascript you would only need to replace the `textContent` property of the element

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('replacer')[0]
el.textContent = el.textContent.replace(/^.{3}/, '***');
```

Answer (score 5):

### A solution which works as you want, try to take a look at it

```css
.replacer {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-family:monospace;
  font-size:18px;
}

.replacer:before {
  content: attr(stars);
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<span stars="***" class="replacer">ABCDE</span>
```

To increase the number of stars in beginning, just change the stars attribute in html, similarly same can be done for `.replacer::after`, see example below

```css
.replacer {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-family:monospace;
  font-size:18px;
}

.replacer:after {
  content: attr(stars);
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right : 0;
}
```

```html
<span stars="***" class="replacer">ABCDE</span>
```

Comment: pay attention, your are not hiding 3 letter

Comment: The OP asked for `***DE`, that's what this CSS does

Comment: you need a monospaced font, I can still see the C in your example

Comment: @fcalderan I made my changes

Comment: by the way don't need to change to after, simply change right/left since the element is position:absolute